# GWT Superdevmode interposing code server for CSS files

Tags: gwt-super-dev-mode

I'm trying to move from Classic to Super dev mode and seeing a problem in the latter. The problem is two-fold. First, it is trying to use the code server to give the css files to the web page. Here is a line from the  element in the resultant web page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:9876/tdome/../resources/standard.css">
```

You can see that it is piping the reference through the code server, which is running on port 9876. Now, that wouldn't be a big deal if it would serve the file. But it won't. The styles in that file are missing in the resultant page. This URL straight to the code server:
http://127.0.0.1:9876/resources/standard.css
... gives "server error". Eclipse is tossing a null pointer exception. It seems to have heartburn with files that are not in the /tdome tree. Just snuffling around and pecking in the names of existing files, sometimes Eclipse says it is ignoring the request. Sometimes it says the file doesn't exist when it does, and sometimes (when it really matters, like here), it gives the nullPointerException. At WebServer.java:272, fwiw.
So I need to either get superdevmode to leave these references alone, or get it to serve the file.
Any ideas? Many thanks-

Answer (score 0):

Well, I really didn't find a way to make Super Dev Mode serve the files where they are. But I figured out where they should be instead of where they are. Probably common knowledge to everybody else: make a 'public' directory next to the 'your-project.gwt.xml' file and put them there. The references to them are in that xml file and do not need any qualification- just the filename, no directory path. Super Dev Mode will package them up, serve them, and let you at them.